# Calculating World Unit or Pixels Per Unit values

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a formula to calculate world unit or pixels per unit values in LibGdx?
 Most of my objects fit into a 32x32 or 16x16 frame. When the objects are close to 32x32, and I use `1f` as the size or 16x16 and use `.5f` things seem to work out fine. What I try to do is use this:

```
// Create viewport that is used to as the game size
static final float VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 15f;
static final float VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 7f;

viewport = new FitViewport(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);

// Scale sizes
final float UNIT_PIXEL = 0.03125f;  // 1 / 32
float newSize = 32f * UNIT_PIXEL;
```

Which seems to work for 32x32 or 16x16. But size problems seem to happen when you try to use that to calculate other widths or heights. Like if I try to use:

```
float newSize = 24f * UNIT_PIXEL;
```

Using this the bounding rectangle becomes much larger than the object.

Comment: Why do you cast like this? `(float)(24 * UNIT_PIXEL)`? This looks like it can cause some rounding issues. Instead do `24f * UNIT_PIXEL`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, it seems to have made a little difference, I'll have to do more testing.

Comment: Can you add what your resize looks like? Also what is the calculated size of your 24px images? It should be `0.75`.

Answer (score 1):

The problems you're having is due to the ratio between viewport width and your images. Currently you're using 15 as a width value and 7 as a height value. This doesn't fit well into 32 or 16.

```
E.g.
32/15 = 2.13333 recurring 
16/15 = 1.06666 recurring
32/7  = 4.57142 etc
16/7  = 2.28571 etc
```

These recurring numbers are causing your conversion values to loose precision.

One way to fix this is to make your viewport width and height a Power of Two the same as your images. so 15 x 7 should become 16 x 8; This way when you want to convert back and forth you can use values without lots of decimal places.

```
E.g.
32/16 = 2
16/16 = 1
32/8  = 4
16/8  = 2
```